# Swift POST body parameters not receiving

Tags: ios, swift, post

I want to login to my server. I already wrote this for android so the server is working fine. I want to rewrite it to iOS using Swift and the params array is not received to the server. It says:

> GET: array (
>   )
>   POST: array (
>   )
>   FILES: array (
>   )
>   ret: {"a":"No such page","r":404}

What am I doing wrong?

```
 func sendLogin(username : String,password : String,myCompletionHandler:(resp:NSURLResponse,d:NSData!,e:NSError!)->Void)->Void {
    var session = NSURLSession.sharedSession();

    NSLog("u:"+username+", pass:"+password);
    var params = ["username":username, "password":password] as Dictionary<String, String> ;
    NSLog(params.description);
    var request : NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest();
    var err: NSError?
    request.HTTPBody = NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(params, options: nil, error: &err);

    request.URL = NSURL(string: url);
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST";
    request.setValue("multipart/form-data", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type");
    //request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept");
    var task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request,completionHandler:{
        ( data: NSData!,response:NSURLResponse!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
        myCompletionHandler(resp:response,d:data,e:error);


    });
    task.resume();
    /*  NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: NSOperationQueue(),

    completionHandler:{
    (response:NSURLResponse!, data: NSData!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
    myCompletionHandler(resp:response,d:data,e:error);


    });*/

}
```

**UPDATE**

The solution was what [Victor Sigler](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2695387/victor-sigler) said. I changed to Alamofire and now it is working. Thanks!

> I strongly recommend you use Alamofire for HttpNetworking tasks – 
>   [Victor Sigler](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2695387/victor-sigler)

Comment: I strongly recommend you use Alamofire for HttpNetworking tasks

Comment: Is there a reason you are using `"multipart/form-data"` instead of `"application/json"` for your `Content-Type` header? Though the 404 error seems to suggest your URL or route is incorrect.

Comment: The url is good the server is sending the answer because it tries to figure out what to do about the params. And while the params array is empty it can't do anything so it sends back 404. The android app is using multipart so i tried it here too.. but i tried with application/json too...

Answer (score 0):

The solution was what [Victor Sigler](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2695387/victor-sigler) said. I changed to Alamofire and now it is working. Thanks!

> I strongly recommend you use Alamofire for HttpNetworking tasks – 
>   [Victor Sigler](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2695387/victor-sigler)